# How to add multiple implementations after AppCompatActivity?

Tags: java, android, class, interface

How to add multiple implementations after extending the AppCompatActivity?

Why am I getting this error? Please correct this piece of code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener,  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
```

You should read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm) too.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `implements` twice to do so, just use it like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
     implements firstImplement, secondImplement {}
```